# Unable to replace arabic characters with Apache POI in a MS Word file

Tags: ms-word, apache-poi, arabic

I need to dynamically modify Word files with values from a database or entered by the user.  The values and files are in arabic.

The problem is that it's not working all the time.  Every time, I encounter a new and different problem with the arabic characters.

Code I am using:

```
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(path+"\\fiches\\"+fileName.trim()+".doc");
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(in);
        HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);
        Range  r = doc.getRange();
         r.replaceText("<matricule>","  "+agent.getMatriculeAgent());
        r.replaceText("<cin>","  "+agent.getCin());
        r.replaceText("<الإسم الشخصي>", " "+agent.getPrenomAgentArabe());
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        response.setContentType("application/rtf");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+fileName);
        doc.write(out);
        out.flush();
```

Comment: Why are you setting an RTF content type when returning a Word Document?

Comment: i set it to msword ,same problem

Comment: And what is that problem exactly? "it's not working all the times" isn't much to go on... We'll need a bit more than that if we're to have much hope of helping you!

Comment: first i had a problem of orientation , i , arabic is right oriented language , this problem was due to that i was writing the variables to be replaced in french ;http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477271/right-to-left-with-apache-poi

Comment: then i'm writting the variable in arabic , example "<الإسم الشخصي>" stands for first name and must be replaced with the user first name from the database , and this is the case for all the words to be replaced

Comment: this not working all the time , every time there is a new deal with this , i have a lot of files to be done like this

Comment: recently, the file modified gives this error ; you can't insert a drawing object in a text zone... , and the file is not opened

Comment: Just a thought: it is probably worth checking to ensure that the sequence of characters in the text you are trying to replace is what you think it is - e.g., you may need to reverse the letters in the RTL (arabic) text. Or you may need to ensure that you are using the correct character forms or combined character forms. There may also be some RTL/LTR directional markers in there.

Comment: the latest hypothesis is when i try to replace a variable with a value which has less number of charachters  , it causes me problem , that makes sense ? how to explain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatly it was not a poi issue , the origin of the problem was the templete i was using , i figured out that text zones or some word features can causes this , template must be the simplest ,ex: a word within a text zone inserted into a table can create a strange behaviour or not be  remplaced ,

Comment: so it is possible that poi handles only simple word features , to be connfirmed please